# How do I use ArrayBuffer/ArrayBufferView to send a Javascript array of strings and Integers through a WebSocket?

Tags: javascript, networking, websocket, arraybuffer

In a small project I'm making to learn more, I'm trying to use as little bandwidth as possible while using a websocket connection and I read that using binary format is a bit more lightweight than using JSON. Normally I would use JSON similar to below.

Client Side:

```
var username = 'Ben2';
var age = 24;
var currentScore = 60;
var userData = {
    Username: username,
    Age: age,
    CurrentScore: currentScore
};
socket.send(JSON.stringify(userData));
```

Server Side:

```
socket.onmessage = function(event){
    var data = JSON.parse(event.data);
    User.username = data.Username;
    User.age = data.Age;
    User.currentScore= data.CurrentScore;
}
```

The solution I'm heading towards is to send a type array of just the values i need without the fields (I'll handle that on the server side, I know this is extremely inflexible and may be frowned upon). Here's What I am thinking of so far.

Client Side:

```
var username = 'Ben2';
var age = 24;
var currentScore = 60;
var data = new Uint16Array([username,age,currentScore])
socket.send(data);
```

Server Side:

```
socket.onmessage = function(event){
    var data = JSON.parse(event.data);
    User.username = data[0];
    User.age = data[1];
    User.currentScore= data[2];
}
```

This would work if all the values I'm sending are numbers, but because I'm using a string for the username, it isn't compatible with the type array. How would I handle this/are Type arrays the right approach for this situation and is this method actually viable to help reduce bandwidth? I may not be fully grasping the concept of converting objects to binary.

Comment: What kind of socket are you using ? Any library or the WebSocket api ?

Comment: Just the WebSocket API

Comment: And the server side ? Are both client and server handled by nodejs or client on browser and server on nodejs ?

Comment: I believe the WebSocket API also, I followed https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API/Writing_WebSocket_client_applications,

the client is in the browser, and server is nodejs

Comment: Ok, I need to see more code (client and server). First I need to see how you catch the socket in the server and after see if connection between client and server is made

Comment: My question isn't so much about how do I make a connection, it's more of, how can I format data into binary and send it.

Comment: Follow this, you will find all you need for the server side : https://hackernoon.com/implementing-a-websocket-server-with-node-js-d9b78ec5ffa8 Note you don't have to transform the client data, the WebSocket browser API does it for you